# What is the best way to position these elements within a div?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to create a structure looking something like this:

[image: struc]

As you can see this involves a main div (div 1) which is centred with respect to the main body of the page. It then includes a second div (div 2) which is aligned to the left of div 1, which is filled in black and contains vertical text.

To do this, I've tried using the following HTML Along with the css code shown below:

```css
.div1 {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
.div2 {
  align: left;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: black;
}
.sidetext {
  color: white;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <h3 class="sidetext">Post #NUM</h3>
  </div>
  <p>The main content (text) for this div is written here</p>
</div>
```

Can anyone see why this might not be giving the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were actually close to the solution, here's where you've missed:

- `align:left;` should be `float:left;`
- with `transform-origin: left bottom 0;` you're rotating your headline out of the black div, better to just rotate around the center and `translate` it to the right position
- add `white-space: nowrap` to ensure the headline is on one line
- wrap your content in a div, in case you have more than just one paragraph.

```css
.div1 {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
.div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  min-height: 15em;
}
.sidetext {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-10em);
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <h3 class="sidetext">Post #NUM</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>The main content (text) for this div is written here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

What's still left to do:
In this example `.div2` and `.content` are not the same height. Also you will have to adjust the numbers for `min-height` and `translateX` to your needs.

Comment: That works perfectly, except it does not increase the height of div2 if the content of div1 is larger than that. How can I fix this?

Comment: I'll update my answer as soon as I can get to it, here's the short version: For same height columns I suggest using flexbox. And while you're at it, consider the answer by @GCyrillus , IMHO that's the best solution, even though browser support is a tad lower. If you really don't want to use flexbox, there are other options, `display:table` is probably the best, but a full discussion about techniques for same-height columns is way out of scope here.

Comment: Thanks, that would be a great help.

Answer (score 6):

I would go for flex and writing-mode, column height's will adjust themselves.

> https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-writing-modes/

```css
.div1 {
  border: solid;
  margin: 1em 10%;
  display: flex;
}
.div2 {
  text-align:center;
  width: 3.25em;
  padding: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: gray;
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  /* old Win safari */
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  writing-mode: tb-lr;
  writing-mode:sideways-lr;/* should be the one */  
  /* eventually IF SIDEWAYS NOT ENOUGH IMPLEMENTED 
  transform: scale(-1, -1); */
}
p {
  border-left: solid;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0.5em;
  flex: 1;
}
/* eventually center text in p */

p {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <h3 class="sidetext">Post #NUM</h3>
  </div>
  <p>The main content (text) for this div is written here</p>
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <h3 class="sidetext">Post #NUM</h3>
  </div>
  <p>The main content (text) for this div is written here
    <br/>here comes a line
    <br/>here comes a line
    <br/>here comes a line
    <br/>here comes a line
    <br/>here comes a line
    <br/>here comes a line
    <br/>here comes a line
    <br/>here comes a line
    <br/>here comes a line
    <br/>here comes a line</p>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zqVgMM)**

Answer (score 1):

Try This:
Add float:left; to your sidebar.

```css
.div1 {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
.div2 {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  margin-right: 10px
}
.sidetext {
  color: white;
  float: left;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform-origin: 22px center 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <h3 class="sidetext">Post #NUM</h3>
  </div>
  <p>The main content (text) for this div is written here</p>
</div>
```

You can check here: https://jsfiddle.net/xmmjrspn/

Comment: Thanks. This solution half worked, but it didn't make the height of div2 the same as the height of div1. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: For same height columns I suggest using flexbox or display:table; both are working good

Answer (score 1):

You need floats to get the sidetext and the p to sit side by side. Additionally if you apply the rotation to div2 and not the text inside, and remove the transform-origin css it will work:

```
.div1{
  width:90%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

.div2{
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
}

.sidetext{
  color: white;
  float: left;
}

p {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
    .div1 {
      border: 1px solid #000;
      width: 100%;
      height: 400px;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 25px 0;
    }
    .div2 {
      background-color: black;
      display: inline-block;
      color: white;
    }
    p {
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="div1">
        <div class="div2">
            <h3 class="sidetext">Post #NUM</h3>
        </div>
        <p>The main content (text) for this div is written here</p>
    </div>
```

here is the jsfieddle link to check  https://jsfiddle.net/ont9sxzx/1/

Comment: QararUlHassan, can you explain something about your code?

Comment: @IgorIvancha he wants to centralized the div and p tag parallel so I create a main div(1) and with text-align: center I centralized the objects in main div and then with display: inline-block I make div(2) and p parallel

Answer (score 0):

`align: left` is a wrong syntax, change to `float: left` and you have it.

Second way:

```css
.div1 {
  position: relative;
  ...
}
.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `float: left` on div2 and have `overflow: auto` on div1. `overflow: auto` will make sure your div1 surrounds div2. Also `position: relative` on the sidetext with a left value to make sure you can see the vertical text. https://jsfiddle.net/sx6e0971/2/

```
.div1 {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: black;
}
.sidetext {
  position: relative;
  left: 45px;
  color: white;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to align sidebar to the left side with flexbox, and then rotate the writing-moded text by 180 degrees.

```
  .vertical {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
```

You can also use `text-overflow: ellipsis` if you want your sidebar height to depend from content height

[codepen](http://codepen.io/vicodin/pen/oxrKPK?editors=1100)

Comment: ?? writing-mode + rotate , one is too much ? (see sideways-rl ) . did you notice my answer  and pen that went along with the snippet http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zqVgMM?

Comment: @GCyrillus yes, liked your snippet, but I think rotated text is looking better

Comment: well `writing-mode:sideways-lr; ` does it wihout rotation need :)

Comment: you should specify this in your answer and add also the code for older webkit/opera and IE browser ;) ( not everyone is aware of autoprefixer working in the backgrounds  )